# P8600, 3gb ddr3 ram, good in 2016?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, lenovo-laptop

I have an old lenovo T400,
Is it ok to use in this era? Is it too outdated? I am using win 10 perfectly on it..

Comment: That depends entirely on what applications you'll be running and what kind of performance you need. If you have specific requirements, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as outdated PC. If it's good for your tasks - it's good, no matter how old. I've bought my laptop in 2008 and it's doing his job very well in 2016. It might be old but not outdated.